# Refresh Database with Imported Data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a datasource that delivers information to me on a monthly basis. Each time, the sql file sent to me contains the entire database. I would like to only import the rows that have been added to the file, not the ones that already exist.

How would this be done?

Comment: Without knowing the full database scheme it is hard to say. But given each table has a unique identifier you should be able to filter out those entries that are already in the database.

Comment: actually, it will be faster to reimport whole database then try to find which rows are missing

Comment: Are previously obtained rows kept unchanged?

Comment: I create my database using a sql query that selects a handful of columns and imports them into my table. If i run the query more than once, I get different values for each primary key in my table... almost like they are not imported in order each time. Is that normal? For this to work, I need them to keep the same autoinc id in my database.

Comment: @DanielP they are unchanged, but have columns added to them.

Comment: Looks like your best shot would be to drop the tables and re-import them from scratch. By the way, with rows I mean records and columns are the "data fields".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using a unique column (and ... into).